# Calculatetable in dax, including instead of excluding

Tags: sql-server, dax, tabular

I am trying to make a set of two organisationplaces, out of a total of 6 places in the table. Instead of excluding 4 places, can I rather include the two I want?

```
EVALUATE
(
summarize(
calculatetable
(
'Organisation',
'Organisation'[Level1] <> "WrongPlace1",
'Organisation'[Level1] <> "WrongPlace2",
'Organisation'[Level1] <> "WrongPlace3",
'Organisation'[Level1] <> "WrongPlace4",
),
'Organisation'[Level2]
)

)
```

Result:

```
Organisation[Level2]
Rightplace1
Rightplace2
```

Comment: what dialect of `mdx` is this? It isn't microsofts version.

Comment: Sorry, It was a brain fart - its DAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but if you just want to explicitly filter two places you want, you could do something like this

```
evaluate
summarize
(
    filter (
        'Organisation',
        or ('Organisation'[Level2] = "Rightplace1", 'Organisation'[Level2] = "Rightplace2")
    ), 
    'Organisation'[Level2]
)
```